# Variance growing in time for event study design

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I have run a regression with a simple event study design.
I use time and company fixed effects and the treatment variable with different time lags without further control variables.
**What could cause the pattern of increasing variance by time?** The population is not balanced, but it has the most observations around time period 0, so it should not cause this pattern and the incompleteness is not so high either.
Details about the setting and the treatment can be read in our working paper, but the event study is not in it yet, this would be a new addition. https://www.mnb.hu/letoltes/mnb-op-137-final.pdf
On the graph relative quarter is 0 at the time of treatment.
I am using the r package lfe for the regression.
[image: Variance growing in time for event study design]

Comment: Before I take a look at the paper, are you working with a panel or repeated cross-sectional data?

Comment: I am working with panel data.